If I started taking over settlements as a raider, could I avoid Preston's wrath and keep my rank as general?
In Fallout 4: Nuka-World, if I started taking over settlements as a raider before talking to Preston or even going to a Minutemen settlement, and I killed all the raiders, could I avoid Preston's wrath and keep my rank as general?

Yes, you can actually even Talk to Preston, and become a raider without locking him out.
The cut-off point is the quest called The First Step. Once you have done this quest you are officially a Minutemen, doing a raider quest after that is counted as Treason and you will lose him. Do Raider stuff before that and you are safe.
